# Regression Tree or Classification tree? multiple categorical inputs and numeric output

Tags: r, tree, classification

It says in the statistics documentation:Classification trees give responses that are nominal, such as 'true' or 'false'. Regression trees give numeric responses. I am trying to build a decision tree. I am working with numeric (output) and non-numeric data(inputs).I think the classification tree would be more appropriate than the regression tree, or (as the regression tree seems to work just with numeric data). Is it possible to use non-numeric data in order to predict numeric data?And if so, how could I do this in R ?Would Classification tree fit be the right choice?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The term "numeric response" is a bit general. Numeric can be a variable that takes values from 0 to infinity (eg. number of users, amounts, distance), but also numeric can be a variable that takes values 1 or 0 (representing yes/no, male/female), or even values 1,2,3 (representing choice 1, choice 2, choice 3). It's better to describe the first case as scale/continuous variables, the second one as binary and the third one as categorical.

The first case can be approached by regression trees (numeric responses based on a continuous variable) and other two can be approached by classification trees (categorical variable response; they might return the categorical value or probabilities for each categorical value. It's up to you).

Check these for a start: http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/cart.html and http://www.rdatamining.com/docs/regression-and-classification-with-r

Comment: Thanks Antonios but how should I handle categorical independent variables? the data is in below format-                                                day, HPorROS ,   device site_name (are Inputs), CTR( output),
 So as u said independent variables are categorical ( with many levels) and output variable (CTR)  is continuous.

Comment: Categorical independent variables are not a problem, as the tree will handle them in a similar way a linear model does. The real problem is if you have MANY levels (compared to the number of rows you have) for at least one independent varaible, which might need another process in advance that will re-group those variables in a way that reduces the number of levels.

Comment: Just to make it more clear how independent variables are used: Case (a) you have an independent variable "age" as continuous in the range [15, 50]. The model might split your variable into different ranges like [15,20], (20,50]. Case (b) you have an independent variable "age" as groups {15-18, 19-30, 31-50}. The model might split your variable into different groups like 15-18 alone and 19-30, 31-50 together.